# Android and iTunes

Tags: sync, itunes

Is it possible to sync an Android phone with iTunes? If so, are there any limitations?

Comment: There is also a question on this at [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/47137/sync-android-with-itunes)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can actually use DoubleTwist in combination with [TuneSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.highwindsoftware.tunesync) (or TuneSync alone) to sync with iTunes although you are limited to songs that are not DRM'd by Apple.

You can also do it without any app on your phone with [Notpod](http://notpod.com/) (Windows only).

The only drawbacks that I am aware with either of these are not being able to use DRM and people have reported some unreliability.  The problem in general with syncing Android with iTunes is that it may work today but if Apple changes something in an update you may get locked out until someone comes up with another work around.  If you are all Android now, I'd recommend on cutting iTunes out of the picture all together.

**Edit:**  Here's a couple other options I've come across that are pretty awesome:

1. [Dazzboard](http://www.dazzboard.com/)
2. [iSyncr WiFi Add-On](http://jrtstudio.com/WiFi_iSyncr).  You need an [app](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=iSyncr) and a desktop client.  The app costs a little but the desktop software is free. This one seems like the coolest option so far.

**Edit 2:**  I happened upon another app...

- [Music WithMe](http://www.appbrain.com/app/music-withme-%28free-trial%29/com.parkvu.android.withme.music.trial): Syncs your phone iTunes over Wifi or 3G.  It doesn't stream the music, it download it to your phone.  Also, I don't think it can handle DRM'd tracks. It's little pricey at $15, especially with the currently less than stellar reviews, but it may be one to watch.

Comment: Dazzboard only fully supports some devices: http://www.dazzboard.com/help/

Comment: +1 for Notpod (previously iTunes Agent). It's just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [Missing Sync for Android](http://www.markspace.com/products/android/missing-sync-android.html) to sync your iTunes playlists (and associated files) to your phone.

It works pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I am aware of, however you could try [Double Twist](http://www.doubletwist.com/) for similar functionality.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is use Google Music, and specifically the Google Music Manager.

1. Go to music.google.com and download the Music Manager.
2. It will run in the background on your computer and upload everything in iTunes, including new downloads/purchases, to Google Music.
3. Finally just download the Google Music app to your Android and you are all set.

A few caveats:

- This seems to be a one-way sync. So deleting a file from iTunes will not delete from Google Music, or vice versa
- The Google Music app on Android is a little different from iTunes/iPhone model. The music is not automatically downloaded to the phone unless you explicitly set it up that way. By default you have to stream the music, which requires an internet connection.
- Apple DRMed content cannot be uploaded to Google Music and therefore won't be transfered using this method.

Comment: Is there an easy way to set it up so the music is downloaded to your phone?