# Can I play DRM music from iTunes on my Android?

Tags: music, drm, itunes

I thought that DRM content on iTunes could only be played on iTunes, but then I saw [SongBird](http://www.getsongbird.com/), a non-Apple application that can play DRM protected music.

Is there an app for that uses similar technology that can play my old iTunes purchases?

Is there any other ways I can play my music on my Android (Wildfire)?

Comment: Related question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/android-and-itunes

Comment: I'll just leave this as a comment as I don't know a full answer.  Short answer: you're going to need to remove the DRM from the music to get most (all?) Android players to play it.

Comment: IIRC, Songbird basically calls up an instance of Quicktime to play the file, then routes the audio through itself. This isn't really the same as playing the DRM'd file on its own, and it requires Quicktime to be installed (which also means it won't work on e.g. a Desktop Linux install or Android).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has basically been answered in the comments above but I'll wrap it all up into an answer:

**No, you can't play songs that have Apple's Fairplay DRM protection on your Android phone without removing the DRM protection** *(which technically violates Apple's toc)*.  As Edarerathis pointed out, Songbird doesn't actually support Fairplay DRM'd media, Quicktime does, so SongBird (like RealPlayer) uses Quicktime to decode the songs and play them.  It wont work without Quicktime installed and so you can't use this functionality in Linux or Android.

Comment: As far as "removing the DRM protection", can you not do this legally by burning the mp3 to CD, then ripping the CD to an mp3 or other DRM free format?  This does take a while if you have a large library, as it requires you to burn to an actual audio CD, not an mp3 one.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the Play Store and looking for 'M4P players for Android'. There are about a dozen choices.

I'm using Video Player for Android to play my older Rolling Stones and Traffic purchases.  Works fine.  Even comes with an equalizer.

Comment: Note that M4P is the extension for [iTunes Audio File](https://www.lifewire.com/m4p-file-2621959). It's different than MP4.