# How can I sync iTunes with a Galaxy Nexus

Tags: music, samsung-galaxy-nexus, itunes

How can I sync my music from iTunes onto my Galaxy Nexus? How-To Geek has a good [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/65164/how-to-sync-itunes-to-your-android-phone/) about using [Salling Media Sync](http://www.salling.com/mediasync/windows/), but apparently the Galaxy Nexus isn't supported because it only shows up as a MTP device in Windows.

Also I'm outside the US so I can't use Google Music (no sure if that would even help though because I don't have access to it! :-o).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/android-and-itunes

Comment: Not voting to close because this question is slightly different since it's applicable to GNex and other phones that only show up as MTP devices.

Comment: @AlEverett Google Music isn't an option because I don't live in the US: "We're sorry. The Google Play music player is currently only available in the United States." :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [isyncr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.iSyncr&hl=en). They have a [wifi add](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.iSyncr.WiFi&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmpydHN0dWRpby5pU3luY3IuV2lGaSJd) on also.

Comment: There are many 3rd-party apps in the Play Store that claim to be able to sync with iTunes: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=itunes+sync&c=apps&price=1

Comment: @Chahk The point is Wi-Fi sync..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: It's a nice feature, but the OP doesn't mention wifi in the question anywhere.

Comment: @eldarerathis Haven't you read this in question: `it only shows up as a MTP device in Windows.`? Without Wi-fi, he is out of option..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: Is he? I have no idea if something like Double Twist/isyncr/et al will work on a device that uses MTP (I don't use iTunes) so the wifi part wasn't really implied to me.

Comment: @eldarerathis Reasoning is simple: When you use USB for syncing (using any app), device must be in mass storage mode (MTP mode is used by Kies type software). His mass storage option is not working, so he can't use USB for syncing. And, Bluetooth/NFC/IR etc. based sync isn't practical. So, wi-fi sync is last option..

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Double Twist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer).

Comment: ...with its `Air Twist` add-on.

Answer (score 1):

[iSyncr](http://www.jrtstudio.com/iSyncr-iTunes-for-Android) works over USB (Mass Storage or MTP), Mac or PC, and also works over WiFi. It handles the Galaxy Nexus just fine.

In full disclosure, I am the developer.