# Create Playlist Folders

Tags: sync, music

I have a huge library of music (nearly 3,000 songs) as it is like that I have lots of folders and playlists inside btw I'm using iTunes. Anyway I want to sync my playlist folders with my S3 and I want to see those foldes in my S3.

Thanks in advance…

Comment: So basically you want to sync iTunes with Android? Have a look at this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/android-and-itunes

Comment: Thanks but will any of those apps sync my playlist folders with S3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a folder on your PC with a bunch of playlist files in them? If so, you could use an app like DropBox to copy your playlist folder to your phone when you change your playlists on your PC. Then you can browse to them using the File Explorer on your phone.

Comment: No I mean iTunes Folder like in this [pic](http://images.pcworld.com/howto/graphics/160799-iTunes_playlist_folders_original.jpg)